# Visual Studio 2017 - Debug and Relese configurations, setting runtime library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I use Visual Studio 2017. I have noticed that runtime libraries for Debug and Release configurations can bet set arbitrary. For example I can set MDd for Debug configuration and MT for Release configuration. Does it make any sense ? Please correct me if I'm wrong but only the following combinations are correct (Debug/Release):

- MDd/MD
- MTd/MT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, "debug" and "release" are just presets for specific compiler and linker settings.

You can set any option to any configuration, no matter if it makes sense or not. The MT options are incompatible, a library compiled with the debug version won't link correctly with a release project.

The same issue occurs with other options as well, these two are the most abused.